# nib file removed but key value connection remains - NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nib

I've been looking through the archives and haven't found a question that answers this. So I'm hoping this is something obvious I'm just missing.

I have an iphone app that's been in the store with various releases over the last 2 years. I finally got frustrated with managing orientation changes through nib files. So I've removed my nib completely from the project and I create all of my fields through code now.

I saw an odd crash in my testing after I'd removed the nib file. But I did some clean up work and couldn't reproduce it. So I've shipped the product. A small subset of my users have seen a crash situation.

I believe I was able to reproduce it in my debugger and got this output.

```
2012-10-22 08:08:22.776 ChakraChimePro[60502:16d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<CCProChimeViewController 0x8578100> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnRingBowl.' 
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1f57022 0x1ccacd6 0x1f56ee1 0x2b6022 0x227f6b 0x227edb 0x242d50 0x78871a 0x1f58dea 0x1ec27f1 0x78726e 0x62d1fc 0x62d779
0x62d99b 0x6490a9 0x648edd 0x6474aa 0x64729e 0x351b 0x564386 0x565274 0x574183 0x574c38 0x568634 0x20eaef5 0x1f2b195 0x1e8fff2
0x1e8e8da 0x1e8dd84 0x1e8dc9b 0x564c65 0x566626 0x2ef6 0x2e25)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

so I've completely removed my class property btnRingBowl. There is no reference to it in the class any more. But I've also completely removed the nib file that was attached to the IBOutlet. So there shouldn't be any reference to it anymore.
Why is my binary still trying to access it?

I've tried deleting the app and reinstalling and the problem goes away.
I've installed the same version of the app that's up on the app store and the problem goes away. I can't reproduce the problem on demand. But I can reproduce it and it's causing crashing for my users.

Since I've completely removed the nib and the properties. I don't know what else I can clean up. Any suggestions?

A string search of my project reveals no reference to this name anywhere.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: you tried reproducing it with the exception breakpoint on?

Comment: Have you tried building the current version over an older version that still had the xib?

Comment: @jackslash I did not try with the exception breakpoint on. This is something that I could try to see if will give me more information. I'll have to look into this as I haven't used this before.

Comment: @yuf Initially I believe I was building over a build that may have contained the nib. But I did a clean. And even went as far as deleting the derived data folder and still saw this error. But then later did not see this error. I think in the case of the released build in the app store I had cleaned out the derived data. But I don't have any way to go back and verify now.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same exact problem.  NIB/XIB files had been removed long ago (before my initial submit), and only with a recent update fix did this pop-up.

I ended up restoring the old nib files from git, and everything worked.  Then removed the broken IB Outlets, rebuild project with those XIB files, and proceed onwards.

I'm not sure if restoring the old nib files will be an option for you, and if not, perhaps rebuilding another nib file of the same name, and force rebuild the project with the new nib file (so it clears the old references out?)